# Scanning .net code and typescript code in a single VSTS build, into a single SonarQube project?

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops

I am trying to scan a .net code and typescript code with VSTS build. The scan should complete in a single build and the results should be published to a single sonarqube project.

For achieving this I have tried the Standalone Scanner -> Manually Provide Configuration option but this did not work. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not using the [VSTS extensions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)?

Comment: I am using Sonar VSTS extension. In the extension task there is a setting Standalone Scanner -> Manually Provide Configuration but that did not work

Comment: Do you have the typescript plugin for SonarQube setup? See: https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=9012568#content/view/9012568

Comment: Yes this is installed